# Buscar valores en un JSON con Python

Tags: python, json

Tengo una pregunta sobre el manejo de *JSON* en *Python*.

¿Cómo realizo una búsqueda exhaustiva de un valor en un *JSON*?

Necesito poner una palabra de búsqueda y hacer que coincida con cualquiera de los valores del objeto.

¿Quizás alguna biblioteca que lo resuelva?

Por ejemplo:

```
[
   {
      "DATAID":"6908409",
      "VERSIONNUM":"1",
      "FIRST_NAME":"Spiderman",
      "UN_LIST_TYPE":"Example List",
      "LISTED_ON":"23\/09\/2014",
      "SUBMITTED_ON":"",
      "NAME_ORIGINAL_SCRIPT":"",
      "COMMENTS1":"Example comment to seach, Rambo is here",
      "ENTITY_ADDRESS":[
         {
            "STREET":"",
            "CITY":"",
            "STATE_PROVINCE":"",
            "ZIP_CODE":"",
            "COUNTRY":"",
            "NOTE":""
         }
      ],
      "ENTITY_ALIAS":[
         {
            "QUALITY":"as.e.e.",
            "ALIAS_NAME":"Example Alias 1"
         },
         {
            "QUALITY":"aa.w.w.",
            "ALIAS_NAME":"Superman"
         }
      ],
      "LAST_DAY_UPDATED":[
         {
            "VALUE":"06\/12\/2019"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Entonces, necesito buscar `"Batman"`, `"Rambo"` o `"Superman"`, y obtener valor si existe o no. Es decir, necesito buscarlos en cualquier lugar de todo el texto.

Las cosas que he intentado, han sido las siguiente:

```py
#Primer intento
search = "[{...}]" # Mi JSON en str()
search = search.lower()
searchWord = "batman"
searchWord = searchWord.lower()
resultado = search.count(searchWord)
print('resultado', resultado) #No ha funcionado

#Segundo intento
resultado = search.find(searchWord)
print('resultado', resultado) #No ha funcionado

#Tercer intento
search = json.loads(search)
if searchWord in search:
   print("encontrado")
else:
  print("no encontraado")
#Tampoco me ha funcionado
```

Gracias.

Comment: Te puedo ayudar con mucho gusto, pero quisiera saber ¿Qué has intentado? No quisiera estarle haciendo la tarea a alguien, eso le da mala reputación al sitio. ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Primero que nada. gracias por tu comentario. A veces no es hacer la tarea, sino simplemente compartir información y experiencias. Ahora edito la pregunta, y agrego las cosas que intenté.

Comment: necesitas buscar en todo el JSON o solo en algunos campos?

Comment: Ese es el asunto, necesito buscar en cualquier valor del JSON. No puedo buscarlo por las claves. Y comparar todas las claves, va a ser muy costoso en procesamiento, porque es un JSON muy grande, con muchos objetos.

Comment: mmm... bueno, se me ocurre una idea

Comment: Te agradecería que la compartieras! Yo comparto otra que leí recién, aún no la probé, aunque tal vez sea un poco tediosa. La idea es pasarlo a un archivo de texto, y luego utilizar la función **grep** del sistema operativo en linux. Aunque espero entontrar una opción mejor directo en python.

Comment: obviamente la voy a publicar pero aun estoy viendo como reducirlo o generalizarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo que simplemente quieres saber si un `string` existe en el *json* (que esta como *string*...) podrías resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

Prueba1:

```
search = "[{...}]" 
search = search.lower()
searchWord = "batman"
if searchWord in search:
   print("encontrado")
else:
  print("no encontrado")
#Resultado: no encontrado
```

Prueba 2:

```
search = "[{...}]" 
search = search.lower()
searchWord = "superman"
if searchWord in search:
   print("encontrado")
else:
  print("no encontrado")
#Resultado: encontrado
```

ta-da~ y eso es todo...

Ahora unos cuantos puntos sobre tu código:

**1)** `search.count(searchWord)` devuelve el numero de ocurrencias del `string` `searchWord` en `search`, es decir, el uso que le diste a `count()` fue el correcto pues devolverá un int con la cantidad de ocurrencias.

**2)** `search.find(searchWord)`, este método devuelve el indice de la primera ocurrencia del string `searchWord` en `search` funciona idéntico al método `index()` con la diferencia de que `find()` no arrojara un error si el valor no es encontrado (en cambio dará un -1), de igual forma, fue usado correctamente.

**3)** `json.loads(search)` , este método del modulo *json* devuelve un diccionario o lista dado un `string`, por tanto la debe ser tratado como estos, en tu caso los objetos están dentro de un arreglo, al hacer `if searchWord in search:` lo que estas es comprobando si en el arreglo superior (que solo tiene un elemento) hay elemento que coincida con `searchWord`.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Lo que comentaste como Prueba 1 y Prueba 2, pudiste hacerlo funcionar? Creo que es lo mismo que hice y no me devolvió el resultado de lo que buscaba.

Comment: Correcto, aunque claro reemplazando el "[{...}]"  con el string del json de la publicación jajaja

Comment: Por favor realiza una prueba con el código de prueba 2 y ven a decirme si te funciono

Answer (score 1):

Espero haberte entendido, ¿Quieres ver cada elemento de tu array de JSONs y detectar si en **cualquier lugar** existe una palabra en específico (tomando en cuenta hasta las propiedades del objeto)? En ese caso lo que podrías hacer es parsear tu JSON a un array para iterar sobre el y luego tratar cada entrada como si fuese una `string` para ver si se encuentra una coincidencia, algo así:

```
import json

datos = '[ { "DATAID":"6908409", "VERSIONNUM":"1", "FIRST_NAME":"Spiderman", "UN_LIST_TYPE":"Example List", "LISTED_ON":"23\/09\/2014", "SUBMITTED_ON":"", "NAME_ORIGINAL_SCRIPT":"", "COMMENTS1":"Example comment to seach, Rambo is here", "ENTITY_ADDRESS":[ { "STREET":"", "CITY":"", "STATE_PROVINCE":"", "ZIP_CODE":"", "COUNTRY":"", "NOTE":"" } ], "ENTITY_ALIAS":[ { "QUALITY":"as.e.e.", "ALIAS_NAME":"Example Alias 1" }, { "QUALITY":"aa.w.w.", "ALIAS_NAME":"Superman" } ], "LAST_DAY_UPDATED":[ { "VALUE":"06\/12\/2019" } ] }, { "DATAID":"64571", "VERSIONNUM":"1", "FIRST_NAME":"Spiderman", "UN_LIST_TYPE":"Example List", "LISTED_ON":"23\/09\/2014", "SUBMITTED_ON":"", "NAME_ORIGINAL_SCRIPT":"", "COMMENTS1":"Example comment to seach, Rambo is here", "ENTITY_ADDRESS":[ { "STREET":"", "CITY":"", "STATE_PROVINCE":"", "ZIP_CODE":"", "COUNTRY":"", "NOTE":"" } ], "ENTITY_ALIAS":[ { "QUALITY":"as.e.e.", "ALIAS_NAME":"Example Alias 1" }, { "QUALITY":"aa.w.w.", "ALIAS_NAME":"Batman" } ], "LAST_DAY_UPDATED":[ { "VALUE":"06\/12\/2019" } ] }]'

#Parseamos el array de jsons
datosArray = json.loads(datos);

#Hacemos nuestra funcion para buscar una palabra en un JSON dentro de un array
def buscarPalabraPorEntrada( arrayDatos, objetivo):
    #Recorremos nuestro array de entradas
    for entrada in arrayDatos:
        #Utilizamos json.dumps para convertir la entrada en una string y usar find
        #Usanos lower() para que no importe la capitalizacion de letras y ampliar la busqueda
        if( json.dumps(entrada).lower().find(objetivo.lower()) != -1):
            print(f"Se encontró la palabra {objetivo} en la entrada con DATAID:{entrada['DATAID']}")
        else:
            print(f"No se encontró la palabra {objetivo} en la entrada con DATAID:{entrada['DATAID']}")
        
buscarPalabraPorEntrada(datosArray,"superman");
```